# Check manually the number of tic tac toe states

Tags: python

I know beforehand that fully-generated tic tac toe game tree contains in total 255 168 different games but I want to convince myself by implementing python program, which counts number of states.

For some reason I get results which are a way too much (611 146) or (269 388). I have implemented game tree generation with depth first search algorithm which saves new branches to open list and explored branches to closed list.

Here is as simply program as I can generate for this problem.

```
import copy

# Creates an empty board 
def create_board(): 
    return([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])

# Check for empty places on board 
def possibilities(board): 
    l = []     
    for i in range(len(board)): 
        for j in range(len(board)):               
            if board[i][j] == 0: 
                l.append((i, j)) 
    return(l) 

# Checks whether the player has three  
# of their marks in a horizontal row 
def row_win(board, player):
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        win = True        
        for y in range(len(board)):
            if board[x][y] != player: 
                win = False
                continue                
        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
    return(win) 

# Checks whether the player has three 
# of their marks in a vertical row 
def col_win(board, player): 
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        win = True          
        for y in range(len(board)): 
            if board[y][x] != player: 
                win = False
                continue               
        if win == True: 
            return(win) 
    return(win) 

# Checks whether the player has three 
# of their marks in a diagonal row 
def diag_win(board, player): 
    win = True    
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        if board[x][x] != player: 
            win = False
    return(win) 

# Evaluates whether there is 
# a winner or a tie  
def evaluate(board, counter): 
    winner = 0   
    for player in [1, 2]: 
        if (row_win(board, player) or col_win(board,player) or diag_win(board,player)):               
            winner = player
            counter += 1
    flat_board = [item for sublist in board for item in sublist]            
    if (flat_board.count(0) <= 0) and winner == 0: 
        winner = -1
        counter += 1
    return winner, counter

# Main function to count number of games 
def play_game():
    counter = 0
    initialized_board, first_player = create_board(), 1
    openlist = []
    closedlist = []
    openlist.append([initialized_board, first_player])
    while len(openlist) > 0:
        board, player = openlist.pop()
        winner, counter = evaluate(board, counter)
        closedlist.append(board)
        if winner != 0:
            winner = 0
            continue
        legal_moves = possibilities(board)
        for legal_move in legal_moves:
            newboard = copy.deepcopy(board)
            newboard[legal_move[0]][legal_move[1]] = player
            openlist.append([newboard, 3-player])

    print(len(closedlist))
    print(counter)

play_game()
```

First I thought that it is enough to count in the end the length of closed list but I'm not sure about it anymore. I did also counter for counting number of terminal states. In my opinion both numbers are incorrect.

Comment: 255,168? are you sure? sounds way too much. The total number of states is 3^9 (3 states for each square, 9 squares), and that's including non-possible ones (ie not stopping playing if a player wins)

Comment: I think you are confusing "states" with "different games". See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613505/251527

Comment: @DeepSpace Not that simple, and probably less since with your method you are counting a board full of crosses for example which is not possible since each player takes turn adding either a cross or a circle.

Comment: @ValentinB. That is exactly what I meant when I wrote "and that's including non-possible ones".

Comment: @DeepSpace A board like `x x o - - - - -` can be generated in two different ways, though, depending on whether `x` first places in the upper left corner or the upper middle first.

Comment: @chepner Indeed, OP used "states" and "different games" interchangeably

Comment: @ValentinB. that doesn't consider stopping when a player has won either.

Comment: @Ð.. figured that out and deleted my comment.

Comment: Sorry my bad, my goal is to get number of different games***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 3**: I moved this part at the top of my answer because it might answer your problem in a more straightforward way by correcting your code. For my solution to the problem, see further below

---

One obvious mistake I can point out in your algorithm is you only took into account 1 of the 2 diagonals in the win conditions. Maybe if you change:

```
def diag_win(board, player): 
    win = True    
    for x in range(len(board)): 
        if board[x][x] != player: 
            win = False
    return(win)
```

to something used in my code:

```
def diag_win(board, player): 
    diag1 = []
    diag2 = []
    for i in range(0, len(board)):
        diag1.append(board[i][i])
        diag2.append(board[len(board) - i - 1][i])
    return all(tile == player for tile in diag1) or all(tile == player for tile in diag2)
```

... your algorithm could work with this !

---

My solution to your tictactoe riddle and original answer:

I haven't figured out what was wrong with your code, but I took a crack at your problem and solved it. I am using an object oriented approach with generators so that memory does not blow up while browsing the tree. My approach is to have each node in the tree save the state of the board, and the board can tell you which moves are possible, allowing a node to generate its own children. Maybe you will find my approach interesting ? Code is below, and produces 255168 as a result so I guess it is correct. It should be able to scale for any board size if your machine can stomach it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from copy import deepcopy


class GameIsFinishedError(Exception):
    pass


class NonEmptyTileError(Exception):
    pass


class OutOfBoundsError(Exception):
    pass


class Board:

    CROSS = "X"
    CIRCLE = "O"

    def __init__(self, board_size):
        self.board_size = board_size
        self.tiles = [[None for _ in range(0, self.board_size)] for _ in range(0, self.board_size)]
        self.moves = {self.CROSS: [], self.CIRCLE: []}
        self.turn = 1

    def play(self, x, y):
        if x >= self.board_size or y >= self.board_size:
            raise OutOfBoundsError()

        if self.game_has_ended:
            raise GameIsFinishedError()

        tile_value = self.CROSS if self.turn % 2 == 1 else self.CIRCLE

        if self.tiles[x][y] is not None:
            raise NonEmptyTileError(f"Tile ({x},{y}) is not empty")

        self.tiles[x][y] = tile_value
        self.moves[tile_value].append((x, y))
        self.turn += 1

    @property
    def board_is_full(self):
        return all(tile is not None for row in self.tiles for tile in row)

    @property
    def someone_won(self):
        # Get values in diagonals
        diag1 = []
        diag2 = []
        for i in range(0, self.board_size):
            diag1.append(self.tiles[i][i])
            diag2.append(self.tiles[self.board_size - i - 1][i])

        for player in (self.CIRCLE, self.CROSS):
            # Check rows
            for row in self.tiles:
                if all(tile == player for tile in row):
                    return player

            # Check columns
            for col in zip(*self.tiles):
                if all(tile == player for tile in col):
                    return player

            # Check diagonals
            if all(tile == player for tile in diag1) or all(tile == player for tile in diag2):
                return player

        return False

    @property
    def possible_moves(self):
        res = []
        for i, row in enumerate(self.tiles):
            for j, tile in enumerate(row):
                if tile is None:
                    res.append((i, j))
        return res

    @property
    def game_has_ended(self):
        return self.board_is_full or self.someone_won

    def print_board(self):
        for i, row in enumerate(self.tiles):
            row = [elem if elem is not None else " " for elem in row]
            row_str = " " + " | ".join(row) + " "
            print(row_str)
            if i != self.board_size - 1:
                print("-" * (self.board_size * 3) + "-" * (self.board_size - 1))
        print()

    def copy_board(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

###################################################################################################
class Node:
    def __init__(self, board, parent=None):
        self.board = board
        self.parent = parent

    def children(self):
        for x, y in self.board.possible_moves:
            new_board = self.board.copy_board()
            new_board.play(x, y)
            yield self.__class__(new_board, parent=self)

###################################################################################################
class Tree:

    UNIQUE_GAME_COUNTER = 0

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    @classmethod
    def step(cls, node):

        if node.board.game_has_ended:
            cls.UNIQUE_GAME_COUNTER += 1
            return

        for child in node.children():
            cls.step(child)

    def browse(self):
        self.step(self.root)

###################################################################################################
#                                            MAIN                                                 #
###################################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    b = Board(3)
    root = Node(b)
    tree = Tree(root)
    tree.browse()
    print(tree.UNIQUE_GAME_COUNTER)
```

**EDIT**: As a side note, this algorithm goes easy on your memory (because at a given time it only holds the states of the board of the current explored branch) but it is CPU intensive. It took roughly 1 minute to run on my machine. If you wish to explore bigger boards I would suggest using multithreading. You can easily give a different starting node to each thread and add up the result at the end.

Comment: After I added also second diagonal check and counted number of terminal states, I got number 255 168! As a conclusion I made in total two common mistakes: 1) I didn't recognized the difference between number of generated states in game tree and number of ways of play/terminal states/game trees or somehow confused them. 2) I forgot to add second diagonal check to program. Thanks for the great answer and hopefully someone finds out this useful in the future!

Comment: You're welcome, you were a tiny mistake away from the solution. I hope you enjoyed my solution, it is more pythonic and I definitely had fun making it. Tried to make it run for a 4x4 board but without multithreading it I'm afraid it would take days to explore all the game tree.